# Number of application running in a particular database

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, oracle12c

We have a legacy application and currently we are using `Oracle12c`. Now we need to migrate all the application to `Exacc`. We have to find out which all the application running in a particular database? We have a common database for many application and we have to migrate only relevant ones.

Could you please let us know is there any way to `find out which all application running on a particular database server`?

Is it possible some other application which also uses same database, so we have to migrate only our application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn on auditing for all sessions with a simple  "AUDIT SESSION" and let your systems run as per normal.

The audit trail will contain the schema names, machine names, os_user plus any other typical session details (module, client_info, action) that all can be used to come up with an educated guess as to what apps are running.

You can also opt to audit every SQL that is executed if you needed to get into deeper detail in order to detemine what is going on.